# How to remove particular same string from string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have large string with repeated some small string in JavaScript. I want to remove only that particular string but symbols should not remove or changed.

The large string is -

```
  var temp="day=1-CT=18-box=calender1_day=2-CT=19-CT=20-box=calender2_day=3-CT=30-box=calender3";
```

IN above string three sub string is joined with underscore(_). so I want to remove 'box=calender(n)' from each from these three sub string. Please help. 
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: what should output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
  var temp="day=1-CT=18-box=calender1_day=2-CT=19-box=calender2_day=2-CT=20-box=calender2_day=3-CT=30-box=calender3";
    str = temp.replace(/box=calender\d/g, '');
    alert(str);
}
myFunction();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple string replacement function. Wherever `box=calender(n)` is found, it will be deleted.

```
temp = temp.replace('box=calender(n)','');
```

Comment: 'box=calender' is same but '(n)' will change in each string.. see the actual above string .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    var temp="day=1-CT=18-box=calender1_day=2-CT=19-box=calender2_day=2-CT=20-box=calender2_day=3-CT=30-box=calender3";
    var pt = /box=calender\d/g;
    temp = temp.replace(pt, "");
```

Comment: 'box=calender' is same but '(n)' will change in each string.. see the actual above string .

Answer (score 0):

may be here is your clue for your search

> $temp="day=1-CT=18-box=calender1_day=2-CT=19-CT=20-box=calender2_day=3-CT=30-box=calender3"; $patterns = array ('/box=calender[0-9]/',); $replace = array ('');
>   echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $temp);

output

> day=1-CT=18-_day=2-CT=19-CT=20-_day=3-CT=30-

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var temp="day=1-CT=18-box=calender1_day=2-CT=19-box=calender2_day=2-CT=20-box=calender2_day=3-CT=30-box=calender3";
temp = temp.replace(/box=calender./g,"");
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P52Aj/1)